# Nginx causes gateway error

Tags: nginx

Below is the file that contains the server configuration of a web service.

```
  1 server {
  2     listen 80;
  3     server_name zabbix.mydomain.com;
  4     root /usr/share/zabbix;
  5     index index.php;
  6
  7     access_log /var/log/nginx/zabbix.access.log;
  8     error_log /var/log/nginx/zabbix.error.log;
  9
 10     location / {
 11         proxy_pass http://localhost:10051;
 12     }
 13
 14     location ~ \.php$ {
 15         try_files $uri =404;
 16         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
 17         fastcgi_index index.php;
 18         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;
 19         include fastcgi_params;
 20     }
 21
 22     charset utf-8;
 23 }
```

After setting up the configuration, I ran `systemctl restart php-fpm` and `systemctl restart nginx` and tried to connect to the website. Then I came to meet the notorious 502 Bad Gateway message.

I also ran `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 10051` to find if the destination is connected, but I could only find the 'connection refused' message. I already have the port 10051 open using the `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=10051/tcp` command.

Any solutions or suggestions?

Comment: Port 15000? Port 15001? Typo?

Comment: Your `proxy_pass` directive transfers to `localhost`, but you write of `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: Give more information on what are the requests that fail and what is in nginx `error.log` when they fail.